# Can we use distance in a SOSL query?

Tags: sosl

Can we use distance field on a SOSL? Below query returns an error

```
FIND {CA} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact (id, CMFSH__Resume_Id__c, name,email,phone,mailingstreet,mailingCity,mailingState,mailingCountry,mailingpostalcode,mailingAddress,distance(MailingAddress, geolocation(37.77829660,-122.41720310), 'mi') dist  LIMIT 1000 )
```

> mailingAddress,distance(MailingAddress,
>   geolocation(37.77829660,-122.41720310) ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:195
>   Malformed search token: ','

While using the same on SOQL runs fine

```
SELECT id,name,distance(MailingAddress, geolocation(37.77829660,-122.41720310), 'mi') dist from contact
```

Comment: The documentation doesn't mention anything about SOSL support, so I don't think it's actually possible.

Comment: Thought so.. just wanted to confirm :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **[`SOQL and SOSL Reference`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_geolocate.htm)** makes mention multiple times of how this functionality is specific to SOQL:

> #### Location-Based SOQL Queries
>
> Location-based SOQL queries let you compare and query location values stored in Salesforce.

---

> #### How SOQL Treats Null Location Values

---

> #### How SOQL Calculates and Compares Distances

---

> #### Location-Based SOQL Query Considerations
>
> Location-based queries are supported in SOQL in Apex and in the SOAP and REST APIs. Keep in mind these considerations.

Given the wording and care taken to specify this functionality as supported in SOQL, it certainly seems to indicate it is the only place where it is supported.